# Compare user input value against dictionary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My macro needs to do some calculations on rows and import data where the user enters an ID. Main thing it's running on the specified ID because there is some data that needs updating/doublechecking so running running the entire source file is not ideal.

My code basically asks the user to enter an ID as 'criteria', and then this gets compared with a dictionary I created containing all data from the source, the problem is that using `dict.Item` doesn't really compare IDs though it runs on every single row correctly in the destination sheet.

```
'dictionary filler
For indexsrsrow = 2 To indexsrslastrow
    dict.Add CStr(srcWorksheet.Range("A" & indexsrsrow).Value), indexsrsrow 
Next indexsrsrow

dim criteria as string
criteria = inputbox("enter id")
For indexdstrow = 2 To indexlastdstrow
    'IF ID EXIST AND ITEM = CRITERIA AND C COLUMN IS EMPTY
    If dict.Exist(criteria) And destinerow.Cells(indexdstrow, "C") = "" Then

    'STUFF HAPPENS HERE

    End If
Next indexdstrow
Set dict = Nothing
```

Is there other way to compare dictionary items with an specified user input?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two suggestions.. `1` Check how the dict is being created. Are you trimming the values before storing? Is there anything else which needs to be noticed? `2` Break the 3 conditions into 3 ifs for the time being and then evaluate them individually to check if it is working. You will have to step through the code for that. At leats that is how I would proceed to check why my code is not working...

Comment: What's `criteria`? and what's it's value? Also, your `destinerow.Cells(indexdstrow, "C") = ""` could throw a false `False` if it has a space. I would `Trim` it

Comment: @Zac `criteria` its the ID the user enters so its like `If id_in_dictionary = id_user_input Then ...`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I broke the If and the problem it's where I compare the criteria with the dictionary, wich stores the column A values (ids)

Comment: What happens when you replace `dict.Item(CStr(destinerow.Range("A" & indexdstrow).Value)) = criteria` with `UCase(Trim(dict.Item(CStr(destinerow.Range("A" & indexdstrow).Value)))) = UCase(Trim(criteria))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Nothing, it enters the if statement and skips non-empty rows but nothing gets printed... I updated the code, it does the same thing but it's "cleaner".

Comment: Can you show the code where you are adding stuff to dict?

Comment: This is one of many `destinerow.Cells(indexdstrow, "C").Value = srcrowsheet.Cells(dict(CStr(destinerow.Range("A" & indexdstrow).Value)), "B").Value` As I said with the code above it runs on the entire file when I only need it in the specified ID

Comment: This is not the code I asked for. I want to see the code where you are adding items to dictionary. How are you creating your dictionary

Comment: Updated the code. @SiddharthRout

Comment: Ok do this. Change `dict.Add CStr(srcWorksheet.Range("A" & indexsrsrow).Value), indexsrsrow` to `dict.Add UCase(Trim(CStr(srcWorksheet.Range("A" & indexsrsrow).Value))), indexsrsrow` And then Change `If dict.Exist(criteria) And destinerow.Cells(indexdstrow, "C") = "" Then` to `If dict.Exist(UCase(Trim(criteria))) And Len(Trim(destinerow.Cells(indexdstrow, "C"))) = 0 Then` Try it now
`

Comment: Running, but still goes through the entire file (doesn't work on the specified id) until finds a id not existing in the source file and a getting a `1004` inside the if.

Comment: If you did as I said and If the ID which the user typed exists in the dict i.e it was present in Col A as well, then the code will enter the `IF` and it will also check if the cell in col C is empty. As for the error, What are you doing inside the `if`

Comment: @SiddharthRout True that, I've been trying for two days but didn't noticed that `if` value is entered the content inside will run as long as if exist, is what I'm asking for even possible with a dictionary?. 
Inside the `if` i'm importing data from that same source file and then I will put some formulas but I'm debugging this first.

Comment: I tried it and it works.. BTW I am assuming that `dict.Exist(criteria)` is a typo? it should be `dict.Exists(criteria)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yeah it works for me too, but it runs on **every row** in the destination file, each row has records with id's but I need it to work **only** on the ids that the user inputs :( sorry for not explaining my problem well enough

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now :D You need to check if the ID is not only in the dict but also in the destination column? If yes then which column is it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Kinda, e.g. Im the user and I need to update the record (row) with id `123` so I run the macro, it asks me for the id that I need to update, I input `123` and when I press enter, in the code it should get the id on the `source workbook`, grab the data and paste it in the `destination workbook` where the id is `123`. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok few quesitons. `1` Which column has the data in the source workbook? `2` Which col is ID in Destination workbook? `3` Where do you want to paste in Destination workbook?

Comment: Ok posted an answer.. have a look at it and change as applicable

Answer (score 0):

> @SiddharthRout Kinda, e.g. Im the user and I need to update the record (row) with id 123 so I run the macro, it asks me for the id that I need to update, I input 123 and when I press enter, in the code it should get the id on the source workbook, grab the data and paste it in the destination workbook where the id is 123. Hope this clarifies. –

I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. Let me know if this is what you want? If not then post your query and I will look at it when I wake up.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet, destinerow As Worksheet
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Set your source and destination worksheets
    Set srcWorksheet = Sheet1
    Set destinerow = Sheet2

    '~~> Add items to dict from Source worksheet
    With srcWorksheet
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            dict.Add CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value), i
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Ask user for the criteria
    Dim criteria As String
    criteria = InputBox("enter id")

    '~~> If user presses cancel or item doesn't
    '~~> exists in dictionary then exit sub
    If criteria = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not dict.Exists(criteria) Then Exit Sub

    Dim rngToCopy As Range, aCell As Range

    '~~> Find the id in source so we can identify the
    '~~> range to copy
    With srcWorksheet
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Find(What:=criteria, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> I am ssuming the data that you want to copy
            '~~> is in Col B. If not then change as applicable
            Set rngToCopy = .Range("B" & aCell.Row)
        End If
    End With

    Set aCell = Nothing

    '~~> Find the id in destinations so we can identify the
    '~~> range where we need to copy
    With destinerow
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=criteria, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> I am ssuming the data WHERE you want to copy
            '~~> is in Col C. If not then change as applicable
            rngToCopy.Copy .Range("C" & aCell.Row)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the dedication and patience! Debugging your code shows that validations are working but no action is taken, the file stays as is.

Comment: Sorry, it actually changes only the first row with that id and overwrites the data if that row contains it.

Comment: So do you want to paste the data to Cell C where it is empty for all rows which contain the ids?

Comment: Yes, only if it's possible, if not I'll just talk to my boss and skip the requirement

Comment: Of course it is possible :) Let me get back home . will post an update in couple of hours